To preserve the forward skew in a stochastic volatility model, are we required to restrict the calibration to part of the Implied Vol surface?
I've understood in my learning journey that LV models have flattening of forward skew especially at longer expiries, and SV models are able to preserve this forward skew. I've the following questions in that context:
1] If we plot the implied forward skew from market implied vols, they display a flattening behavior, because the spot smile has flat skew for large expiries. Would this be a correct statement?
$$
\sigma_{12,\text{IV}} = \sqrt{\frac{\sigma_{2,\text{IV}}^2 T_2 - \sigma_{1,\text{IV}}^2 T_1}{T_2 - T_1}}
$$
2] Is it correct to say that LV models have flattening of forward skew because of the nature of the market implied vol surface itself? For example, if the market did not have skew flattening of spot smile for large expiries, then there wouldn't be flattening of implied forward skew, and subsequently the forward skew from the LV model also wouldn't show flattening behavior.
3][a] For an SV model, how is it possible to calibrate to entire implied vol surface, and also preserve forward skew, at the same time? If this is indeed possible, does this mean that the forward vol from an SV model does not match the same from the implied vol surface?
3[b] Or is it that if an SV model preserves the forward skew, then it cannot calibrate to the entire implied vol surface. For example, it might calibrate to the short end of the surface, and preserve the forward skew, and subsequently the skew of spot smile for large expiries would be larger than that implied by the market, and hence the SV model doesn't calibrate to the long end of the surface in this case.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

They say a good question is half the answer. My impression is that you're struggling a bit with what it is you really want/need to know. Maybe mull on it a bit more and then streamline and edit your question?
